# PyQt translate changed data from disk onto the TreeView without reloading the model

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt

I am new to PyQt and the MVC pattern. I have created an application which parse the xml file and renders the data in a TreeView. The changes made my the user in the GUI is rightly saved to the corresponding xml file.

*Problem* : When the user changes the xml file on the disk, I trigger file-changed signal and that in turn reloads the model. But because of this coarse load- strategy, meta information, like the collapse-state of the displayed tree or the selected object get lost.

*Question* : As the model is built upon the xml file, the changes made by the user to the xml file on the disk would generate a new model. I would like to know if there any efficient way to propagate the changes from the disk to the TreeView, without setting the TreeView with the new model every time the file has changed?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help you and understand what you are doing.

Comment: There is no simple solution for this. You will need to find a structured xml-diff tool that can analyse the changes in a way that allows for incremental transformations from one state to another. A brief search found [xtdiff](https://github.com/cfpb/xtdiff), which looks quite promising.